# Initial Boot Lockup - "Started Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch"

Tags: boot, 16.04, lockup

Freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04-LTS from USB using mkusb-nox utility on a good linux system. During the initial boot of the machine after virgin system build, the boot sequence locks up at the following message:

[ OK ] Started Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch

I have built at least 8 Ubuntu servers without ever having this type of problem.

How can this be fixed and diagnosed?

Date of build - 1/12/2017 @ 7AM PST

Comment: Please describe the computer. Is this standard Ubuntu or Ubuntu Server? And is this the original 16.04 LTS or the first point release 16.04.1 LTS? The first point release is much improved after months of debugging and polishing.

Comment: [   40.123457] NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s! [systemd-udevd:1129] is the message. I have rebuilt the system and attempted recovery of the system 3 times. I am using the ISO image from the Ubuntu web-site, specially: ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64

Comment: BOXNUC5CPYH, Intel Celeron N3050 Processor, DDR3L SDRAM, Support 2.5in HDD/SSD, Gigabit Ethernet, WiFi, Bluetooth, USB 3.0, HDMI.

Comment: 4G DDR3L RAM and WD 500G SATA HD 5400RPM

Comment: I have an Intel NUC6i3SYH, and it behaves well for me. I can boot it in UEFI and BIOS mode from internal drive, USB and even the built in SD card reader seen as an MMC device. I have a couple of laptops, where the debian installer of Ubuntu Server fails, but it works in my NUC. But you have another NUC, probably with another BIOS system, mine is Intel Visual BIOS SYSKLi35.86A.0024.2015.1027.2142 . Did you check the iso file with md5sum? Have you checked if there is an updated BIOS? Have you checked the RAM with memtest?

Comment: Updated BIOS from PYBSWCEL.86A.0054.2016.0503.1546 to PYBSWCEL.86A.0058.2016.1102.1842. Still locking up. I will attempt another USB system rebuild.

Comment: Replaced memory. Still locks up. I will try to build another system. Either the hardware is bad or the OS is bad (drivers, etc.). I have eliminated everything I know.

Comment: I know that you want a server, but it might add some information, if you try some desktop iso file. Boot from USB, "Try without installing" for example Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, TahrPup, Debian Jessie (there is a light-weight  live iso with LXDE).

Comment: I have been able to successfully bring up the system described above using 16.10 server. The final configuration for this machine:

1) Upgraded BIOS to PYBSWCEL.86A.0058.2016.1102.1842.
2) Swapped 4GB of RAM to 8GB RAM. I originally thought I had a bad memory stick, however, the 16.04.1 build still did not work.
3) Using the following bootable ISO: 7d6de832aee348bacc894f0a2ab1170d  ubuntu-16.10-server-amd64.iso (MD5).

I do not have any insight between the 16.04.1 LTS and 16.10.

Comment: Congratulations  :-) I think the main difference is that there is a new linux kernel in 16.10, which is better fit to work with new hardware. - And of course, some bugsare squashed, both in the kernel and in the other software packages including the hardware drivers.